# Validation in paper-input troubleshooting, how to?

Tags: javascript, regex, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have this `paper-input` element definition:

```
<paper-input label="time_of_birth"
             required=True
             prevent-invalid-input
             allowed-pattern="([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]" 
             placeholder="00:00"
             error-message="24 hour formatted HH:MM">
</paper-input>
```

The regex works great [here](https://regex101.com/r/dJ7yU5/3). However, when I attempt to enter values (running under the `polyserve` server), no keyboard input is allowed at all. There are no errors in the Dev Tools console, nor does the error message appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your usage of `allowedPattern`, which is meant to specify the set of characters (i.e., a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)) that could be entered, and this property blocks all other characters when paired with [`preventInvalidInput`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input#property-preventInvalidInput). For *HH:MM* time values, `allowedPattern` should be digits or colon (i.e., `[\d:]`). You likely meant to set an input pattern that specifies the required format of the value. For that, you should instead use [`pattern`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input#property-pattern).

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(_ => {
  "use strict";

  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    _submit: function() {
      console.log('submit', `valid: ${this.$.input.validate()}`);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.6.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <form is="iron-form" action="">
        <paper-input id="input" label="time_of_birth"
             required
             prevent-invalid-input
             allowed-pattern="[\d:]"
             pattern="([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]" 
             placeholder="00:00"
             error-message="24 hour formatted HH:MM">
        </paper-input>
        <paper-button on-tap="_submit">Submit</paper-button>
      </form>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/RRVZgv?editors=1011)

Comment: Okay, I see now. The docs and the name 'allowedPattern' then are really a misrepresentation. It isn't a 'pattern' at all. It is a list of allowed characters. The documentation differs between iron-input and paper-input. Maybe these could be updated. It maybe too late to change the name of the property but as long as it is well documented it would be helpful. Thanks the solution works.

Comment: `allowedPattern` is technically a regex pattern (a character class), but I agree the docs could be updated to better explain its usage.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex will validate 33:33. You should use this pattern:

```
allowed-pattern="^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$"
                 ^ makes the regex match the whole input $
```

PS: This should be in a comment, but I do not have the necessary reputation to comment.

Comment: Thanks but the start and end markers aren't used in HTML or XML pattern matches.